# Xamarin Forms Listview Items Not Displaying

Tags: list, azure, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list in my Xamarin Forms app that I have being bound to data. This all works and I know I am getting data because if I tap on the screen the list shows the data, but I assume the list should show each item without having to tap on the screen.

Here is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PDInstall.Views.LayoutsPage"
             Title="Layouts">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="layoutsList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      Refreshing="layoutsList_Refreshing" ItemTapped="layoutsList_ItemTappedAsync">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
public LayoutsPage (Job job)
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    _job = job;

    Task.Run(() => GetLayoutsListAsync());
}

private async Task GetLayoutsListAsync()
{
    if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        layoutsList.IsRefreshing = true;

        IList<CloudBlockBlob> layouts = await azureFileUpload.ListJobBlobsAsync(_job.JobId);

        IList<CloudEditableBlob> layoutList = new List<CloudEditableBlob>();

        foreach(var item in layouts)
        {
            CloudEditableBlob editableBlob = new CloudEditableBlob();

            editableBlob.Name = item.Name.Replace(_job.JobId.ToString() + ": ", "");

            editableBlob.Container = item.Container;

            editableBlob.Parent = item.Parent;

            editableBlob.StorageUri = item.StorageUri;

            editableBlob.Uri = item.Uri;

            layoutList.Add(editableBlob);
        }

        layoutsList.IsRefreshing = false;

        await Task.Run(() => layoutsList.ItemsSource = layoutList);

    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No Internet Connection", "Please Reconnect to the Internet and re-open PDInstall", "OK");
    }

    layoutsList.EndRefresh();
}
```

I am getting a list of blobs from azure, they are just PDFs that we have stored. I get the list of blobs then I have to put it into a custom class, so I can change the name, then I put that into the list. This all works fine up until it tries to show the list and I get a blank page until I tap it where it then shows the list.

Does anyone know if I can programmatically do a tap or something to get that list to show? Or possibly another way to get the data show without having to tap on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, you should optimize your code a bit. You're already calling `GetLayoutsListAsync` on a background thread so you don't need to when setting the `ItemsSource`, and all ui changes should be done on the main thread, which is probably why it's not showing up when set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
await Task.Run(() => layoutsList.ItemsSource = layoutList);
```

With

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{ layoutsList.ItemsSource = layoutList; });
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked thank you! I didn't know about BeginInvokeOnMainThread.